# Using Upper(substr( capitalizing first letter

Tags: sql, plsql

Trying to get my head around PLSQL

So I want the firstname (fnamn) and lastname(enamn) to have its first letter in uppercase. Been googling around a lot, and found topics regarding it and been testing for a while now but dont get it to work.. Only managed all letters to be upper when trying.

Here's my code so far;

```
declare 
cursor c_användare 
is select upper(substr( fnamn,1)) ,Enamn,pnr  
from bilägare; 
v_fnamn bilägare.fnamn%type; 
v_enamn bilägare.enamn%type; 
v_pnr bilägare.pnr%type; 

begin 
if not c_användare%isopen then 
open c_användare; 
end if; 
loop 
fetch c_användare 
into v_fnamn,v_enamn,v_pnr; 
exit when c_användare%notfound; 
dbms_output.put_line(v_Fnamn||', '||v_Enamn||', '||v_pnr||'år'); 
end loop; 
close c_användare; 
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is **`INITCAP`**.

```
select initcap('jOHn') as first_name, initcap('smItH') as last_name from dual
union all
select initcap('JÁNOS')             , initcap('KÁDÁR')              from dual
;

FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME 
---------- ----------
John       Smith     
János      Kádár
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
UPPER(SUBSTR(fnamn,1,1)) || SUBSTR(fname,2)
```

SUBSTR() takes the 1-based first index, and then a length.  If the length is omitted, the entire field is returned, so `SUBSTR(field,1)` is the same as just `field`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, greatly appreciated.